# How to speed up inserts in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

There is a large amount of data to be inserted, around 200 mln rows. Cassandra itself is not the real bottleneck - there are some related heavy calculations before the data is inserted, so the MR distrubuted model would be great. In other words, it would be great to split the calculations between many nodes and then collect the data in one place - upload it to a single node that will store all the data, and shutdown other (not used anymore) nodes.

Something like that:

```
node1 - processes data chunk1
node2 - processes data chunk2
nodeN - processes data chunkN
...
[result] all the chunks are collected together and merged into single big dataset
```

How to do that and save time? I thought about writing binary SSTable files by each node, and then simple uploading them to the main instance (yes sounds too simple but who knows?..) So - is there any way to do that? Or - if no - what would be the best 'traditional' way to do that? SSDs, RAIDs, clusters with multiple nodes?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered running a Hadoop job over Cassandra?  See https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/examples/hadoop_cql3_word_count for a HelloWorld type of tutorial.

Comment: @DanielS. ok that's good, though we use Disco for map-reducing, not Hadoop =(